# Applet Fish Drawing

Tags: java, swing, applet, drawing, java-2d

I redid the program from the ground up following an example from my textbook on drawing a snowman. It runs and draws my fish, however I'm not sure how to hollow out the tail and the fin ovals with a triangle. (The oval is all yellow, I want to insert a green triangle in each one so it looks like a pacman)

```
//**********************************************************************
// Fish.Java    Louis Colucci
// Draws a fish
//**********************************************************************

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import java.awt.*;

public class Fish extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics page)
    {

    final int MID = 300;
    final int TOP = 100;


    setBackground (Color.green);

    page.setColor (Color.white);

    //Draws the body
    page.setColor (Color.blue);
    page.fillOval (MID-70, TOP+70, 360, 120);

    // Adds the name Jascha Heifetz to the body
    page.setColor (Color.black);
    page.drawString ("Jascha Heifetz", 365, 240);

    //Draws the fin
    page.setColor (Color.yellow);
    page.fillOval (MID+75, TOP+40, 85, 45);


     //Draws the tail
    page.setColor (Color.yellow);
    page.fillOval (MID+275, TOP+90, 140, 75);

    //Draws the eye
    page.setColor (Color.yellow);
    page.fillOval (MID+0, TOP+100, 12, 12);

    //Draws the mouth
    page.setColor(Color.white);
    page.drawArc (MID-68, TOP+105, 75, 30, 190, 110);
        }
}
```

Comment: 1- Start by using a `JPanel` which is added to the `JApplet` 2- Override the `JPanel`'s `paintComponent` method. 3- Call `super.paintComponent`. 4- Have a read through [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 2):

Well your basic code is wrong. You should not override the paint() method of a top level container like JApplet (JFrame...). Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Then you can check out the tutorial on [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for examples of painting different shapes.